# Injecting an answer into an install file in Linux

Tags: linux

I am trying to write a .sh script to download, install, and configure a certain application. I can get the file downloaded with wget, chmod +x the installer file, call the installer file, however, the EULA shows up with --More-- at the bottom and I can not get the script to inject the 'q' key to get to the accept/deny area of the EULA. If I manually hit the 'q' key the script continues and will inject my 'y' into the next part. Here is what I have so far.

```
chmod +x installer.x86_64.rpm.bin
./installer.x86_64.rpm.bin<<EOD
q
y
EOD
```

Comment: are you really missing the closing `!` for your HERE document or is that a typo? That could be the problem. Add `!` on a line by itself, without any spaces or tabs preceding. Also, while it's less typing, `!` can be interpreted by shells as a history substitution, I'd recommend using something that is a little more self-documenting, i.e. `EOD` (end of data) or many other inititialisms or words. Good luck.

Comment: Sorry, I must have missed the copy. I do have it in my .sh script. Sorry! EDIT: I did what you recommended to make it more legible. Thanks

Comment: Try setting the PAGER environment variable to cat, as in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9086517/eula-accept-bash-script. If that doesn't work, do you have expect installed?

Comment: Try `echo y | PAGER=cat ./installer.x86_64.rpm.bin`. Or even `PAGER=true` if you want no output.

Comment: Sorry that didn't fix it, but the other comments look promising. Good luck.

Comment: melpomene, Your PAGER=true works with the original script I have. It goes right to the EULA acceptance screen and takes the 'y' from the script.